# Need to replace a excel value with another value from another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

Need to replace a excel value with another value from another sheet. Some values do not need replace so I need a formulas or code to recognize that. Both sheets aren't in the same order. For ex.
columns "Division thru Alt_rep"(6) are the updated values to replace in(200 + rows) 
sheet 2 "Division thru Alt_rep"(14000 + rows)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please see [our guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for posting questions. Specifically, `Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.`

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine it would be `.Find` and `.Offset` to copy data from the other sheet to current sheet:

```
Dim t_val as Variant

t_val = other_sheet.Range("A:A").Find(What:="value to lookup", LookIn:=xlValues, _ 
        LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True).Offset(0, 2)

current_sheet.Range("G:G").Find(What:="value to lookup", LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True).Offset(0, 6) = t_val
```

I had to use variant for a different macro, and it can be done without that... but this is what I think should work? The offsets need to coincide to where you want the data to be unless there is no need to offset. In that case you can just take that out and then all you need is:

```
other_sheet.Range("A:A").Find(What:="value to lookup", LookIn:=xlValues, _
       LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True).copy _ 
       destination:= current_sheet.Range("G:G").Find(What:="value to lookup", _ 
       LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True)
```

Comment: What exactly does the range represent? Columns or rows?

Comment: This is my code: Dim t_val As Variant

t_val = Sheet2.Range("A3:H281").Find("A3:H281", LookIn = xlValues, LookAt(xlWhole, MatchCase = True).Range("A2").Offset(280, 281).Select)
        Sheet1.Range("A1:Q40194").Find("A1:Q40194", LookIn = xlValues, LookAt(xlWhole, MatchCase = True).Range("A1").Offset(40193, 40194).Select) = t_val   Keep getting "Compile error: invalid out procedure.

Comment: yea that's all wrong....

what the code is supposed to be doing is going to a specific range (either column or row or combination of either) and finding a specific id such as "apple" and returning/copying that specific id to a different range (either column or row or combination of either)

Comment: the offset is a function that will say go to this range in this specific cell and now put the value in the # of column or rows away from that cell as indicated in the offset parameters --> offset (0,1) is therefore 0 rows away 1 column away... so put result in the same row but next column

Comment: i think it might make sense for you to broadly outline what you are trying to accomplish... i.e. go to sheet 2 and take all the values in col A and copy those values to sheet 1 in col A

Comment: Basically I'm trying to replace 6 columns of values from another sheet , instead grabbing values from all 281 cells(time consuming)

Comment: yea... i would spend some time familiarizing yourself with vba tutorials, etc. it is going to be hard to reply to your question if you are unfamiliar with what a range() means..